# Why Many to Many relationship with self can't be symmetrical

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a model with many to many relationship to itself and this relationship will also have a specific table that will store some information about the relationship, but I'm running into some problems.

I tried to make a many to many relationship with diferent models like the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) say, and it's worked fine in some other point of my application. But now I tried to do something like this:

Let's say that I want a model that represents an object (called Item) that is made by other items and also is used to make some other items. For instance, an object Door is made by wood and lock, but Door will also be used to make a House. I thought in something like this for my models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    items = models.ManyToManyField("self",through='IsMadeBy')

class IsMadeBy(models.Model):
    itemResult = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='itemResult')
    itemPart = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='itemPart')
    amountUsed = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical.
```

So, adding the argument

```
symmetrical=False
```

to my relationship the error stops.

With that being said, I want to know how this really works under the hood. For intance, what the symmetrical means in this context in a database level? I would appreciate if anyone could give examples maybe using SQL statements, since right now my brain can't see the overall situation and really learn this concept of symmetrical relationship in a many to many relationship with self.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

With symmetric relationship if i'm your friend then you my friend too - in Django terms, you have one relation.

With non-symmetric direct and reverse relations can be different, you have related_set. For example, if i'm you manager, you not my manager at the same time, but manager via employee_set can have many employees.